# Date Range in elastic search in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

Am using elastic search for my codeigniter project . Here i have to collect data with a particular date

```
$params['index'] = ES_INDEX ;
            $params['type'] = ES_REQ_TYPE ; 
            $params['size'] = 30 ;
            $es_start = strtotime("17-05-2018") * 1000; 
            $es_end = strtotime("16-05-2018") * 1000; 
            $params['body']['query']['bool']['filter'][] = array('range' => array('happenon' => array('gte' => $es_start, 'lte' => 'now/d')));
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($params);
            exit;
```

Also happenon(time stamp value in string at database) value is created time .. That also in the format like a string

```
[happenon] => 1526667686216
```

So How can i get last 90 days data in elastic search